# Changing DIV height based on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to minimize my navigation bar once the user has scrolled past the header. I pretty much have it good to go, I was just needing some advice on how to handle the line height of the elements as the div is shrunk. Also, when scrolling erratically the navigation bar will glitch and sometimes will still be shrunken even though I am at the top of the page. Could someone help me solve this issue? Thank you very much in advance.
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Quench</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <header id="site-header">
            <nav id="main-navigation">
                <ul class="soc" >
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Specials</li>
                    <li>Location</li>
                    <li>Events</li>
                    <li class="social" style="text-align:center;">
                    <a class="soc-twitter" href="#"></a><a class="soc-facebook" href="#"></a><a class="soc-pinterest" href="#"></a>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>


            <div class="logo">
            Quench
            <span>Satisfying Nightlife</span>
            </div>
            <div class="fore-glass">
            </div>
        </header>

        <section>
            <article>
                <header>
                <h2>Article Title</h2>
                </header>
                <p>Today massive amounts of penguins migrated to the warm waters of the Pacific Ocean</p>
            </article>

            <article>
                <header>
                <h2>Article Title 2</h2>
                </header>
                <p>German Sheperd kills man and small child walking in neighborhood park</p>
            </article>
        </section>

        <aside>
            <h2>About Section</h2>
            <p>Welcome to Quench the greatest site ever known to man</p>
        </aside>

        <div style="height:2000px"></div>

        <footer>
        Copyright 2015-2016 Quench.
        </footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

***style.css***

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:#130806;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Candara, "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
color:#fff;
}

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


img {
    max-width:100%;
}

footer {
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}

header#site-header {
background:url(images/bar-background.jpg);


background-size:100% 600px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
color:white;
width:100%;
height:600px;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;

}

header#site-header .fore-glass {
    position:absolute;
    background:url(images/bar-glass.png);
    background-position: center top;
    background-size:25% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    right:6%;
    bottom:10%;
    width:50%;
    height:70%;
    z-index:6;


}

header#site-header .logo {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:10%;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:90px;
    font-weight:900;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:-100px;
    line-height:1;

}

header#site-header .logo span {
    font-size:80px;
    font-weight:500;
    font-style:italic;
    opacity:.7;
    color:#607927;
}

header#site-header nav#main-navigation {
    width:100%; 
    background:#607927;
    height:100px;
    font-size:24px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:5;
    transition : all 100ms ease-in-out;

}

header#site-header nav#main-navigation li {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
header#site-header nav#main-navigation li.social {
    margin-top:15px;
    line-height:100px;
}

header#site-header nav#main-navigation ul li ul > li {
    display:block;
    float:none;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}


/* Social */


@font-face {
    font-family: 'si';
    src: url('fonts/socicon.eot');
    src: url('fonts/socicon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/socicon.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/socicon.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/socicon.svg#icomoonregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family:si;
        src: url(PATH_TO/socicon.svg) format(svg);
    }
}

.soc {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:right;
}

.soc li {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;

    text-align:right;


}

.soc li a {

    font-family:si!important;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;

    -o-transition:.1s;
    -ms-transition:.1s;
    -moz-transition:.1s;
    -webkit-transition:.1s;
    transition:.1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    overflow:hidden;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: none;
    display:inline-block;

}

  .soc li a.soc-pinterest {
      margin-right:0px;
  }

.soc-icon-last{
    margin:0 !important;
}

.soc-twitter {
    background-color: #41501B;
}
.soc-twitter:before {
    content:'a';
}
.soc-facebook {
    background-color: #41501B;
}
.soc-facebook:before {
    content:'b';
}
.soc-google {
    background-color: #d93e2d;
}
.soc-google:before {
    content:'c';
}
.soc-pinterest {
    background-color: #41501B;
}
.soc-pinterest:before {
    content:'d';
}
.soc-linkedin {
    background-color: #3371b7;
}
.soc-linkedin:before {
    content:'j';
}
.soc-rss {
    background-color: #f26109;
}
.soc-rss:before {
    content:',';
}

.soc-twitter:hover {
    background-color: #3993ca;
}
.soc-facebook:hover {
    background-color: #2a4784;
}
.soc-google:hover {
    background-color: #c52a19;
}
.soc-pinterest:hover {
    background-color: #b51205;
}
.soc-linkedin:hover {
    background-color: #1f5da3;
}
.soc-rss:hover {
    background-color: #de4d00;
}




article {
    padding:100px 0;
    max-width:640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;


}
```

***main.js***

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(e){

  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  $(".logo").css({

     "transform" : "translate(0px, "+ scroll / 2 +"%)"

  });   

  $("header#site-header .fore-glass").css({
      "transform" : "translate(0px, "+ scroll / 4 +"%)"
  });

  $("header#site-header .fore-glass").css({
      "opacity" : 1-(scroll / 600)
  });




   var mainNav = $("header#site-header nav#main-navigation");
   var navHeight = $(mainNav).height();
   var navItems = $("header#site-header nav#main-navigation li");
   var socialItem = $("header#site-header nav#main-navigation li.social");
   var socialText = $("header#site-header nav#main-navigation li.social span");


  if(scroll >= 500){

      var navNewHeight = (scroll < 550) ? 100 - (scroll - 500) + "px" : "50px";
      console.log("Scroll:" + scroll);

      $("header#site-header nav#main-navigation li:first-child").css({
          "transition" : "all 100ms ease-in-out",
          "font-weight" : "bold"
      });

      mainNav.css({
         "transition" : "all 300ms ease-in-out",
         "height" : navNewHeight 

         });

      navItems.css({
          "transition" : "all 100ms ease-in-out",
          "line-height" : navNewHeight
      });

       socialItem.css({
           "transition" : "all 100ms ease-in-out",
           "line-height" : navNewHeight/2
       });

      socialText.css({
          "display" : "none"
      })



  }



});

});
```

Here is the Fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/AFTef/1101/

TLDR 
Looking for advice on how to go about updating line-height of main-navigation as user scrolls past header.

Also, How can I fix the issue where if you use the scroll bar very fast, the header may be minimized when it should be full size?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the relevant source code? This isn't a free programming service here at your request.

Comment: added code snippet and fiddle, my apologies

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AFTef/1101/ correct fiddle link, sorry it's one of those days :P

Comment: Why the rain of downvotes? He's new here...

Comment: @Shomz New or not, he didn't include the relevant source code so that would make the question appear to be a request for free source code. Since the OP has updated the question I have removed my down vote.

Comment: @NewToJS, oh, I see. When I saw the question, it already had (too much of) the code, and an updated fiddle in the comments, so I thought the downvotes are because he posted the full code and not only the relevant parts.

Comment: @Shomz check the OP edits, if you notice downvotes and no source code then it kinda adds up but I think people should remove the down votes now that the question is acceptable.

Comment: You are correct. I just gave him an upvote for the effort because usually none of the downvoters return later to see if the question is fixed.

Comment: @Shomz Good point, upvote will remove the down vote. Since mine is gone, you have removed one downvote with your upvote. I will upvote so only -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you basically have two states (not counting the "transitional" state between 500 and 550 pixels), I'd strongly suggest you drop all the manual CSS rule creating in JS, define the two states in CSS (for example, as a class of the body element, or `#site-header`), and use JS only to switch that class on and off, based on the scroll.

Another reason why I'd do it is to avoid setting CSS transitions dynamically, combined with other rules because that's suspectible to a degree of randomness. For example, you're setting a height transition as well as the height itself, and chances are the height will be implemented/changed first, and the transition rule would be implemented second, but nothing will happen since the height change had already happened (hope this doesn't sound too confusing).

CSS3, although very limited with the types of animations you can do, performs way better than JS animations and is ofter much simpler to control. Unless you're working on something that CSS3 cannot do, of course.

---

Here's the super-simple example of what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/AFTef/1102/

Comment: Hey, you're welcome, hope that wasn't too confusing. I'm going to update my answer, with a super-simple example of what I meant.

Comment: Nice, this seems to remove the glitches I was having. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, whenever it's possible to do an animation in CSS, do it in CSS. In this example, you just need to fine-tune all the rules because I only wrote two of them and there are a couple more of them.

Comment: The one issue with this solution is that when the browser is scrolled to exactly 500 pixels, the navigation doesn't sit flush with the content. This was a problem I was running into so I decided to try and update the actual pixels dynamically

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Generally, problems like those are fixed by using z-indexing or changing the header class a bit later (say, at 550px: http://jsfiddle.net/AFTef/1103/), letting it slide "under" the header before that. Also, you can use [CSS calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to perform simple calculation if you still wish to update pixels on every scroll.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you got it going. :)